# Power Apps Searching on multiple columns in Gallery

Tags: search, gallery, powerapps

I have a gallery that is linked to a SharePoint List. I want to be able to search 3 fields with the 3 search boxes. Now I made 3 search boxes for ID, Name, and Last Name. I can get it working when searching for 1 field but when I try to modify it to search across multiple fields, it breaks.

```
Filter(tbl_mas_employee,StartsWith(Title,txtEmpCode.Text))
```

What modifications need to be made to the above function to be able to use the 3 search boxes?
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtFzJ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Filter(SHAREPOINT_LIST,
    Or(
        StartsWith(spColumnName1, txtBox1.Text),
        StartsWith(spColumnName2, txtBox2.Text),
        StartsWith(spColumnName3, txtBox3.Text)
    )
)
```

**Consider doing this differently for performance and delegation reasons.**

1. `OnVisible` of the screen, create a *collection* from the Sharepoint List

   - Ensure your filter condition is [delegable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwiErbYtRdA).

```
ClearCreate(colRecords,
    Filter(SHAREPOINT_LIST,
        condition = someValue
    )
)
```

2. Have 1 textbox for searching (`txtSearch`)

   - Set its `HintText` property to something like `Search by Title, column2, etc.`
   - Set `DelayOutput` property to `true`
3. Set the gallery `Items` property to:

```
Filter(colRecords,
    Or(
        txtSearch.Text in Title,
        txtSearch.Text in column2,
        etc...
    )
)
```

Then its really easy to add another column. Also the user experience is quite nice.